# MVC3 Routing - How do I get the URL when inside the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

Can someone tell me how I can get the URL that was used to call my route when I am in the controller?  It seems simple but I can't find any reference on how to do it. If u need an example I can explain more .. Previously I asked a route question and someone told me how I could check which route was met. This time my needs are a bit different.

Thanks,

Mandy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Use the Url property of the Request object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.url.aspx).

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    var url = Request.Url;

    /// .....

    return View();    
}
```

[That will return a Uri object with everything you need](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx).

You might also be interested in the controller's [RouteData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492210.aspx) property, which provides more detailed information about the parsed route.

Comment: Thanks a lot David. Your answer is perfect. I had been looking at RouteData. I saw there was a url property in that but could not get to it. Do you have any idea why that is? Mandy

Comment: @Mandy I don't see a .Url property on RouteData when checking via Intellisense, though I could be looking in the wrong place. RouteData should only store a list of the route component tokens (typically, `controller`, `view` and `action` as defined in your route) and their values, which is what the controller is really concerned with as it could be called from different urls. If you need the literal url, you'll need to use Request.Url.

Answer (score 6):

Since you have a reference to the Request property of Controller, you can just do:

```
var url = Request.Url.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the RouteData.Values property instead of the Request property.  The Request property will probably be null in the unit testing scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Routing debugger to see what url matches your controller / actions

[more information](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx)